# What do you call a USB flash disk?

Tags: word-choice, colloquialisms

I assume usually you don’t say *USB flash disk*, right?

By the way, in Chinese we call it something more like *U Disk*.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive

Comment: We call them "Data Sticks" in my company.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Conversationally, I've usually heard them called a *drive* (not a *disc*).  Here in the U.S.,  I've heard all of these terms used:

> - Flash drive
> - [Thumbnail](http://wisegeek.com/what-is-a-thumbnail-drive.htm) drive
> - USB drive

It will be interesting to hear what others say; this might be a regional thing.

By the way, I was curious: I typed "flash drive" and "U disk" into Google Images (in "quotes"), just to see what kind of results I'd get.  (That's not a bad way to see if a term means what you think it means. Both searches yielded plenty of pictures of the devices in question; however, "U disk" yielded over one million results, while "flash drive" returned more than 32 million.  Such a disparity might suggest that the latter is a more common term, though this is a very unscientific method, and should not be treated as incontrovertible evidence.)

Comment: USB drive tends to imply external hard disk drive around here, and flash drives may be understood as internal SDD.

Comment: Sometimes just thumb drive

Comment: We call them "jump drives" around the office because we think that's hilarious.

Comment: +1 for [flash drive.](http://www.microcenter.com/search/search_results.phtml?add_Ntt=flash+drive&search_within_go.x=0&search_within_go.y=0&Ntt=usb+drive&Ntk=all&Ntx=AllPartial&sortby=match)

Comment: I've never heard it called a "thumbnail drive", and I would interpret that term as a misremembering/corruption/portmanteau of "thumbnail-as-in-small-picture" and "thumb drive".

Comment: @Martha: Maybe it is exactly that, but, if so, [I'm not the only one who has misremembered the term](http://www.tapeonline.com/products/maxell-usb-drives-503053) :^).

Comment: Also: http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-thumbnail-drive.htm

Comment: I've also heard "jump drive," and I commonly hear "thumb drive" but NEVER "thumbnail drive."

Comment: Calling filesystems “drives” is a very CP/M kind of thing.  Smacks of Micro$oft to me.

Comment: @alcas: Maybe it's regional, I don't know, but the term IS used. (I've supplied two links as evidence.)

Answer (score 8):

Not yet stated, I have always referred to them as *memory sticks*.

Comment: Forgot about this one, even though it is the one I always call them. Edited my answer below as you reminded me of it and +1'd you :)

Comment: I suppose [memory stick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_stick) is only used by SONY?

Comment: Yeah, Memory Stick would probably work for most people, but would cause confusion with anyone who was familiar with Sony products because it is a brand name for them. You'll notice even on the Wikipedia article, they have a disambiguation notice at the top directing people looking for USB flash drives.

Comment: Wow, I never knew memory stick was brand-oriented! I guess it's the new "hoover"!

Answer (score 6):

I know lots of people, me included, who call them *jump drives*.

It is like Xerox and Aspirin. *JumpDrive* is/was a Lexar name for their flash drive, but even [Wikipedia’s article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive) on USB flash drives recognizes *jump drive* as a term.

[WiseGeek](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-a-jumpdrive.htm) says:

> JumpDrive is a Lexar brand name for a Universal Serial Bus (USB)
>   storage device, also called a USB flash drive (UFD). As is sometimes
>   the case with brand names, the term “jumpdrive” is occasionally used
>   by consumers when referring to any USB flash drive, in the same way
>   “Kleenex” is often used to refer to any brand of facial tissue.
>   Technically, the industry refers to these devices as UFDs, though
>   consumers are mostly unfamiliar with the acronym, more often using
>   terms like memory stick, thumb drive, or flash drive.

Answer (score 5):

Here (Scotland) I have heard it called:

- USB key
- USB drive
- Flash drive
- Pen drive

Comment: Also in Scotland, I'd often use "USB thingummy".  I've also heard people simple calling them a USB, e.g. "Has anyone got a spare USB?".

Answer (score 5):

In the US I mostly hear equally:

- USB drive (literally sounds too general, but everyone knows it's the small thing)
- thumb drive (sounds strange because it's not as thick as your thumb, but everyone knows it's the small thing).
- flash drive (literally the most accurate, not evocative of the size, but everyone knows it's the small thing).

Answer (score 2):

I call it a USB stick, and if I need to be specific I might call it a USB thumb drive.

Some thoughts to keep in mind when looking for a name:

Thumb/Flash/Pen/...

- It normally uses *flash* memory, meaning that data must be written in large blocks.
- It is sometimes shaped like a pen, so it *could* be called a pen drive.
- It isn't some kind of hardware *key* (like a thumbprint reader), though it could contain a software key. And it is small enough that you could put it on a keychain. However, I don't really think this works very well.
- USB drive normally implies an external hard-drive (whether solid-state or disc) with a USB connection. A USB thumb drive is technically external, but minus the stereotypical USB cord.
- They are normally about the size of your thumb so calling it a USB thumb drive works fine.
- I've never heard of a fire-wire thumb drive, so just calling it a thumb drive will probably work.

And no, they don't use discs.

Answer (score 2):

People call it *flash disk* in Indonesia, or sometimes just *flash*.

Comment: It isn’t just Indonesia. That’s what I always use, too.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, the main terms I have heard them referred to as are *USB drive*, *memory stick*, and *pen drive*.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen anyone calling it "USB data disk" conversationally yet.

The most commonly used name is "pendrive" (sometimes spelled as "pen drive"), even if the form factor doesn't resemble a pen at all.

Pendrive yields 116,000,000 Google hits. Pen Drive - 35,100,000.

Comment: As a side note, _most_ don't look like a pen, although [some do](http://richupongroupphil.com/computer-gadgets/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/USB-Pen-Drive-pd-110-300x278.jpg).  Maybe that's where the term originated?

Comment: I'm in the U.S. (Midwest) and I've never heard of a pendrive or pen drive.

Comment: My sister had one of those pen drives, but its capacity is sadly inadequate to today's needs. Plus, the ink ran out.

Comment: I have never in my life until 30 seconds ago here heard of a “pen drive”.

Answer (score 1):

*USB stick, thumb drive,* or a *memory stick* are the most common terms I hear for them in the United States.

*Disk* is a term for a physical item put into a computer that isn't much used any more like a hard or floppy disk or a CD. Or it could be the disk drive that is built into the computer, so using the term *USB flash disk* would confuse someone from the USA, but the person would probably get that you mean the little stick thing that plugs into a computer and holds files on it.

Answer (score 1):

In India, *pen drive* is used frequently among common peoples. In the colloquial language its more prevalent. But *flash drive* is also now coming slowly in to the picture. In India many manufacturers uses this term readily.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet stated, in the country I live it is also called "Cool Disk".

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it called:

> USB; *do you have your USB on you?*
>
> Flash disk
>
> Memory stick